# Running parallel bash jobs on a HPC cluster using GNU parallel

Tags: cluster, gnu-parallel

On an HPC cluster I am trying to run multiple bash scripts (`permute2.sh`) from 1 bash script using GNU parallel, however it doesn't complete every job. It randomly completes one job, while it is stuck doing the other.

**permute1.sh:**

```
PROCS=144 
permuations=1000
seq 1 $permuations | parallel -j $PROCS sh permute2.sh {}
```

**permute2.sh** (taking 100 random lines from a file and performs some actions on it for permutation)

```
id=$1
randomlines=100
awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {a[NR]=$0}
END{for(I=1;I<='$randomlines';I++){x=int(rand()*NR);print a[x];}}'
FILE.txt > results/randomlines.$id.txt

# do stuff with randomlines.$id.txt..
```

When I run  `permute1.sh` I can see it creates 144 files, for each cpu 1  (randomlines.1.txt - randomlines.144.txt), but most of them are empty and stopped working, and some are completed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running this job as part of a batch file on your cluster?  Are there limitations set by the resource manager that limits the number of processes or files you can execute?

Comment: I tested your programs on my laptop and it finished with no problems. So it is likely a problem limited to your system. My guess would be file handles. Use --joblog logfile to see what jobs failed. Use --retries 3 to try a failed job 3 times.

Comment: When i just 'qsub' the jobs, they all get completed perfectly. so i got it working now... There must be some limitations indeed, but I'm not getting a response from the helpdesk (its a PBS system btw). i'll just not use parallel for these occasions..

Answer (score 1):

Your `ulimit -u` is < 144. Have an admin change that.